# CSS :not selector has no effect

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to give the  tag the class `no-color`. Only if Javascript is activated the class `no-color` is removed and the text shall be colorized. My current CSS is not working. Here a sample code. I don't need a solution that adds a class to the `p-tag` because this is just a sample code.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on9oh2zd/)

SASS

```
:not(.no-color) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="no-color">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using uncompiled SASS in your fiddle, and that is why it is not working. Have you tried compiling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `div` to your selector [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/on9oh2zd/1/)

```
div:not(.no-color) {
  p {
    color: red;
 }
}
```

Or in pure `CSS` that would be `div:not(.no-color) p`

```css
div:not(.no-color) p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-color">
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>hello world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `div` selector before `:not`

```
   div:not(.no-color) {
      p {
        color: red;
      }
     }
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/on9oh2zd/4/

Answer (score 1):

you should add div like this:

```
div:not(.no-color) {
  p {

    color: red;

  }
 }
```

your code can't find measurance